# Does CKEditor's "config.removePlugins" setting affect its loading time?

Tags: ckeditor

I have a custom CKEditor build. Eventually, after I've done code changes, which I don't want to lose, I decided that not all of the plugins, which I included in the initial build, were necessary, so I removed some of them through the `config.js` file by using `config.removePlugins`.

My questions are:

Does this method improve the loading speed of the editor at all or does it remove the plugins after they have been loaded?

If the first is true, does it only affect the loading of resources from the `plugins` folder or does it also affect the loaded content of the `ckeditor.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the Full package from CKEditor [download page](https://ckeditor.com/download) then while loading the editor, the whole package gets loaded even if `config.removePlugins` is used.

The less plugins you have, the faster the editor loads. This is the general rule.  Another one is that the editor **should be served in release and not the source mode**.

The best practice is to get the editor source code from [here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_source), create your own fork which you can update to newest stable branches, create your custom plugins and build your own custom editor release according to this [link](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_build).

This way you will get all the plugins you want and the editor code will be minified, obfuscated and combined into a single `ckeditor.js` file which should guarantee the fastest load time.